# Is required register a list of Objects in Hive?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

This is my Hive model and I already generate the adapter:

```
@HiveType(typeId: 7)
class GoalModel {
  @HiveField(0)
  bool progessNotificaitons;
  @HiveField(1)
  List<DayModel> daysToWork;
  @HiveField(2)
  int amountGoal;
  @HiveField(3)
  DateTime initialDate;
  GoalModel({
    this.amountGoal,
    this.daysToWork,
    this.initialDate,
    this.progessNotificaitons,
  });
}

class DayModel {
  String label;
  int index;
  bool gonnaWork;
  DayModel({
    this.gonnaWork,
    this.index,
    this.label,
  });
}
```

The issue is that does not allow me save the `daysToWork` which is a list of the class `DayModel` which does not have an adapter. the question is: is required generate an adapter or any special config to save a list of a type of object?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The response is YES, is required generate an register a new adapter even if you just are going to issue the object into a list of another object.